# Group by, summarise and return the value back to the dataset in R?

Tags: r, grouping, normalization

I am trying to create summary statistics without losing column values. For example using the iris dataset, I want to `group_by` the species and find the summary statistics, such as the `sd` and `mean`.

Once I have done this and I want to add this back to the original dataset. How can I can do this, I can only do the first step.

```
library("tidyverse")
data <- (iris)  
data<-data %>% 
group_by(Species) %>% 
summarise(mean.iris=mean(Sepal.Length), sd.iris=sd(Sepal.Length))
```

this looks like  this

[image]

I want to then add the result of `mean` and `sd` to the original iris data, this is so that I can get the z score for each individual row if it belongs to that species.

For further explanation; essentially create groups by the species and then find z score of each individual plant based on their species.

Comment: Use `mutate` instead of `summarise`? `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(mean.iris=mean(Sepal.Length), sd.iris=sd(Sepal.Length))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like

```
library("tidyverse")
data <- (iris)  
df <- data %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(mean.iris=mean(Sepal.Length), sd.iris=sd(Sepal.Length))

data %>% left_join(df, by = "Species") %>% 
  mutate(Z = (Sepal.Length-mean.iris)/sd.iris)
```

Answer (score 1):

Though there already is an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67053129/8245406), here is a way of computing the Z scores for all numeric variables.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), scale)) %>% 
  rename_with(~str_c(., "_Z"), where(is.numeric)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  left_join(iris, ., by = "Species") %>%
  relocate(Species, .after = last_col())
```